# Shared codebase for ESP 32 and 8266?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, esp32

From https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/

> the firmware can now be run on any ESP module

Apparently the modules are not considered firmware as many are completely different.

Example: wifi on esp32 does not have wifi.sta.getip() but uses wifi.sta.on(). NTP vs TIME is totally different as well.

So, what are suggestions to maintain a single codebase or is that not even practical?

Comment: the RTOS IDF framework is now available for esp8266 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have agreed on a plan to merge the two code bases. A number of preparation task have either been completed or are currently being worked on. As (developer) resources are scarce it will take us a while to get there.

> Apparently the modules are not considered firmware as many are completely different.

One doesn't contradict the other. It's just that currently there are two different firmwares for the two hardware families.

Comment: Thanks Marcel. That's good to hear. I appreciate everybody's effort. I really like the improvements in the ESP32 firmware and wish eventually move that to my ESP8266 modules.